# What counts as a "kill" for killstreaks?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I noticed when playing Domination that capturing a domination point counted as a kill as far as kill streaks are concerned. I think I may have also received "kills" by destroying aircraft. What all things now count toward kill streaks in MW3?

Also, do these now count as actual "kills" (ie, show up on the leader boards?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MW3's new point streaking system means numerous actions now count toward your killstreak rewards; plants, defuses, captures, defends, kills, and even assists (with Hardline Pro) count now.  Destroying killstreak rewards (helicopters, SAMs, turret guns, etc.) will count against your killstreaks, for every strike package.

These do not count toward your actual kills (in terms of K/D ratio, leaderboards, game limits, etc.) - only toward your killstreak rewards.

Comment: What about shooting down killstreaks?  Do you have to have a particular strike package for them to count?

Comment: Destroying killstreak rewards (helicopters, SAMs, turret guns, etc.) will count against your killstreaks, for every strike package.